# How to fix: 'Error occurred in generator: subscript out of bounds'

Tags: r, keras, time-series

I have been playing around with neural networks in Keras. When trying to apply recurrent neural networks I stumbled across a blueprint of code, but when implementing the code and trying to adjust it to my needs, I always receive the error:

```
Error occurred in generator: subscript out of bounds
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  StopIteration: 

Detailed traceback: 
  File "/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 181, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/reticulate/python/rpytools/generator.py", line 23, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/reticulate/python/rpytools/generator.py", line 40, in next
    raise StopIteration()
```

The dataframe that I'm using is just a timeseries of one variable. My suspicion would be that the generator is the culprit but I'm not 100% certain.

I would gladly appreciate your guys's help.

I have tried experimenting with different versions of the fit_generator() function, but everyone of them throws the same error.

```
generator <- function(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index, shuffle = FALSE, batch_size = 128, step = 2) {
    if (is.null(max_index)) max_index <- nrow(data) - delay -   1
   i <- min_index + lookback
   function() {
     if (shuffle) {
       rows <- sample(c((min_index+lookback):max_index),size = batch_size)
     } else {
       if (i + batch_size >= max_index)
         i <<- min_index + lookback
       rows <- c(i:min(i+batch_size, max_index))
       i <<- i + length(rows)
 }
     samples <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows),
                                 lookback / step,
                                 dim(data)[[-1]]))
     targets <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows)))
     for (j in 1:length(rows)) {
       indices <- seq(rows[[j]] - lookback+1, rows[[j]],
                      length.out = dim(samples)[[2]])
       samples[j,,] <- data[indices,]
       targets[[j]] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay,2]
     }
     list(samples, targets)
   }
 }

lookback <- 30
step <- 2
delay <- 365
batch_size <- 128 

train_gen <- generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = 1,
  max_index = nrow(data),
  shuffle = TRUE,
step = step, 
  batch_size = batch_size
)
val_gen = generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = floor(nrow(lightning_ts_red)*0.6)+1,
  max_index = floor(nrow(lightning_ts_red)*0.8),
  step = step,
  batch_size = batch_size
) 
test_gen <- generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = floor(nrow(lightning_ts_red)*0.8)+1,
  max_index = NULL,
  step = step,
  batch_size = batch_size


test_steps <- (nrow(lightning_ts_red) - floor(nrow(lightning_ts_red)*0.8)+1 - lookback) / batch_size


val_steps <- (floor(nrow(lightning_ts_red)*0.8) - floor(nrow(data)*0.6)+1 - lookback) / batch_size
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
train_gen,
steps_per_epoch=500,
epochs=20,
validation_data= val_gen,
validation_steps = val_steps,
verbose=1, view_metrics="auto")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this line in the generator function:

```
targets[[j]] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay,2]
```

The second argument, 2, defines which column of data you want to predict. In the original example (from Chollet and Allaire) the Temperature in Celsius was in second column ('T (degC)'), and that's what they were trying to predict.

If you're working with univariate data you only have one column, so the generator function will throw 'subscript out of bounds' error.

You should change it to 1 (as below) and it should work fine.

```
targets[[j]] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the total number of data as for `train_gen`, it can be better if you divide the data and explicitly give the number of rows to take as for `train_gen`.

I have done as follows and works for me. I have time series dataset with 8614 rows:

```
train_gen <- generator(
data, 
lookback= lookback,
delay = delay,
min_index = 1,
max_index= 5500, # you say that the first 5500 value consider as a training data
shuffle = TRUE,
step = step,
batch_size = batch_size
)

val_gen <- generator(
data, 
lookback= lookback,
delay = delay,
min_index = 5501, 
max_index= 7000,
step = step,
batch_size = batch_size
)

test_gen <- generator(
data, 
lookback= lookback,
delay = delay,
min_index = 7001,
max_index= NULL,
step = step,
batch_size = batch_size
)

## How many steps to draw from val_gen in order to see the entire validation set
val_step <- (7000 - 5501 - lookback) / batch_size
test_step <- (nrow(data) - 7001 - lookback) / batch_size
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it didn't fix it. I'm still getting the same error. The index indication I gave was just in terms of the datalength.
'max_index = floor(nrow(lightning_ts_red)*0.6)' 
would give me 60% of my data as the training portion of the set, if I'm not mistaken. I tried inserting your suggestion but I still received the subscript out of bounds error.

Comment: try to calculate first the value of Val_step and test_step as your nrow(data) and consider the batch_size. If the val_step and would be less than 1, you will get the subscript out of bounds error! val_step = (max_index - min_index - lookback) / batch_size

Comment: I don't quite get your comment. As of now both val_step and test_step are 17, or would I need to define them within each of the generator functions? If I do it outside of them neither max_index nor min_index is defined.Thanks in advance ;)